# CSS animation does not work on iPhone/iOS12.2

Tags: ios, iphone, css

Below css animation works perfect on the old iOS versions.

However, it does not work proper on newest version, iOS12.2.
The animation starts and works when first visiting website. But after reloading browser, it does not start animation.

Any solutions?

```css
.button {
 display: block;
 width: 400px;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: gray;
 position: relative;
}
.button:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: -75%;
  width: 25px;
  height: 50px;
  content: '';
  display:block;
  background-color: white;

  -webkit-animation: shine 1.5s ease 0.5s infinite normal;
  animation: shine 1.5s ease 0.5s infinite normal;
}

@-webkit-keyframes shine {
  0% { left: -75%;}
  50%, 100% { left: 125%; }
}

@keyframes shine {
  0% { left: -75%; }
  50%, 100% { left: 125%; }
}
```

```html
<a class="button">Hello
</a>
```

Comment: Can you make this a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: which browser are you viewing  on (and which vsn of the browser)

Comment: I added full code. Please run code snipet.

Comment: OS: ios12.2   Browser: safari

Comment: Could you add list of browser plugins?

Comment: no plugins using for the browser.

Comment: What about Safari version?

Comment: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1

Answer (score 0):

Try the following example - before make sure that you clear browser cache:

```css
.button {
 display: block;
 width: 400px;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: gray;
 position: relative;
}
.button::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 50px;
  content: '';
  display:block;
  background-color: white;

  -webkit-animation: shine 1.5s ease 0.5s infinite normal;
  animation: shine 1.5s ease 0.5s infinite normal;
}

@-webkit-keyframes shine {
  0% { left: -100px;}
  50%, 100% { left: calc(100% + 80px); }
}

@keyframes shine {
  0% { left: -100px; }
  50%, 100% { left: calc(100% + 80px); }
}
```

```html
<a class="button">Hello
</a>
```

Comment: The animation works on the first landing on the website. But it stops after reloading as same as my code... > iOS12.2: Safari